# Minor ticks missing on only some graphs

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, matplotlib

My code pulls in csv files, subsets the data, then interates through each data frame to produce an output and some graphs.  The code works for all my test data except two subset data frames of one csv file.  The problem is the minor ticks from 0 to 100 are not showing up on the two output graphs.  I've looked over the data, I can't see why the minor ticks wont show.

I tried setting the major axis with this code,

```
locmaj = matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator(base=10.0, numticks = 6)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(locmaj)
```

But that doesn't help even if I set the numticks equal in the minor loglocator line.  It does produce an interesting behavior where 0 and 1 don't show on the y axis at all.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(df['cunnanes'],df['turbidity'], s = 4)
ax.scatter(exceed['exceedance'], exceed['turbidity'])

ax.set_title(names[i] + ' Exceedance graph')
ax.set_xlabel('Exceedance Probability (%)')
ax.set_ylabel('Turbidity (FNU)')
ax.set_yscale('symlog')
ax.set_ylim([-0.5, 10000])

ax.minorticks_on
ax.tick_params(axis = 'x', which = 'both', direction  = 'in', top = True, bottom = True)
ax.tick_params(axis = 'y', which = 'both', direction  = 'in', left = True, right = True)
locmin = matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator(base=10.0,  subs=(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(locmin)
ax.yaxis.set_minor_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.NullFormatter())

plt.show()
```

Any ideas what could trigger this behavior?

Not working graph:
[image: Not working graph]

The working graph:
[image: The working graph]

Update:  Here is the offending csv file and the min code to reproduce the problem.

[Data](http://www.filedropper.com/wft2)

[Script](http://www.filedropper.com/exceedancemincode)

Update 2
Jody Klymak pointed out matplotlib.ticker.SymmetricalLogLocator() instead of LogLocator().

Changed

```
locmin = matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator(base=10, subs=(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9), numticks = 10)
```

to

```
locmin = matplotlib.ticker.SymmetricalLogLocator(linthresh=1, base=10, subs = (0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9))
```

Comment: Possibly it's a bug, but one cannot find out without [mcve] to reproduce.

Comment: I'll work on a stripped down version.

Comment: Is there a reason to not use the SymLogLocator? https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.SymmetricalLogLocator

Comment: Thank you!  matplotlib.ticker.SymmetricalLogLocator() was the answer.  Odd that loglocator worked for everything but these two specific subsets.